# How to validate or sanitize arabic number input-data?

Tags: javascript, validation, event-handling, arabic, keyevent

My task is to allow users to type arabic text in my input field, however they are unable to do so due to a function named `isNumber()` in the code. Without the `isNumber()` function, the users are able to type arabic text. I'm inspecting the code and I can't figure out why that function isn't allowing users to accepting arabic input.

[I've reproduced this error in code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-leaf-g21k5w)

The next provided example code is the boiled down variant of the above linked sandbox code.

```js
function validateLength(value, maxLength) {
  if (value.length >= maxLength) {

    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function isNumber(evt, maxLength = 30/*1000000*/) {
  // evt = evt || window.event;
  const value = evt.target.value;

  if (!/*this.*/validateLength(value, maxLength)) {

    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  const charCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (
    charCode > 31 &&
    (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) &&
    charCode !== 46
  ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
document
  .querySelector('input')
  .addEventListener('keypress', isNumber);
```

```css
[type="text"] { display: block; width: 50%; }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="01234٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩56789" />
```

Comment: for now it is not allowing any input.

Comment: This might be difficult for people with non-arabic keyboards to test for you, is it specifically on codesandbox.io or have you seen this function not working locally for instance?

Comment: It allows english numbers

Comment: How about adding a try/catch in the isNumber function and outputting error?

Comment: It doesn't work locally as well @user115014. It allows for english numbers but not arabic numbers

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not just a link to an external resource that might break in the future.

Comment: Yeah let me try that @user115014

Comment: I guess you are trying yo put only numbers so, you can make an array of the required number and then check the condition

Comment: The answers look good, adding `console.log(charCode)` before the if/else will help you identify the Unicode values needed to clear them.

Comment: 1/2 ... A possibly less complex approach was to listen to any `input` event (including pasted and deleted content) where a sanitizing method always assures a valid field value. Such a task would remove any non digit character from the current input value and also limit the latter to its maximum allowed length ... `const { value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = event.currentTarget; const sanitizedValue = evt.currentTarget.value.replace(/[^\p{N}]/gu, '').slice(0, maxlength);`...

Comment: 2/2 ... It then would rewrite the sanitized value and reestablish a meaningful selection range of the input field ... `const deltaLength = value.length - sanitizedValue.length; currentTarget.value = sanitizedValue; currentTarget.setSelectionRange(selectionEnd - deltaLength, selectionEnd - deltaLength);`. ... there is neither a need for shooting at unicode character ranges nor for a handler's boolean return value nor for fiddling around with preventing event defaults.

Comment: @MohamedRifaath ... just [boil the example code down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to an input field and a `keydown` handler implementation provided as [executable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Then the thread hopefully will be reopened which opens a chance again for more helpful answers to your problem.

Comment: @MohamedRifaath ... the OP's thread got opened again and meanwhile received another answer. Are there any questions left regarding this lately provided approach / solution?

Comment: No it's clear, I have a much better understanding on this topic. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @MohamedRifaath ... Then the OP might consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer which was most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isNumber` function only permits typing in the text box if the [key code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is within the range of the [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) number character codes. The key codes on an Arabic keyboard will correspond to the [ASCII Arabic Codepage](https://www.ascii.ca/cp864.htm) instead.

Note that a key code is a distinct concept from a Unicode character code, and that [the key code approach is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which).

A key code is the decimal ASCII (RFC 20) or Windows 1252 code corresponding to the key. The operating system and/or browser may (will) map this value to a Unicode character, which will have a different identifying number.

You have two ways of fixing this:

1. Continue using key codes and check for [the ASCII Arabic codepage values](https://www.ascii.ca/cp864.htm) if the user has configured their machine to work in Arabic (you need to do this check because other languages will use different codepages THAT MAP TO THE SAME NUMBERS), or
2. Use a Unicode-first approach (see below).

Unicode-first approach:

In order to make this work for [users who wish to use Arabic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/languages) you will need to:

1. Use [`input` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) or [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key),
2. Identify what Unicode codepoints correspond to the Arabic numbers (see below), and
3. Permit entry of the Unicode codepoints corresponding to Arabic numbers. Checks can be performed using [String#codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) or a regular expression with the `u` (Unicode) flag set.

Arabic codepoints are located in the 13th Unicode block (range `U+0600` to `U+06FF`). You can see the codepoints [in this document](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf).

```
0660 ٠ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO
0661 ١ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE
0662 ٢ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO
0663 ٣ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT THREE
0664 ٤ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FOUR
0665 ٥ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT FIVE
0666 ٦ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT SIX
0667 ٧ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT SEVEN
0668 ٨ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT EIGHT
0669 ٩ ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT NINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach was to listen to any `input` event (including pasted and deleted content) where a sanitizing method always assures a valid field value.

Such a task would remove any non digit characters from the current input value and also limit the latter to its maximum allowed length. It then would rewrite the sanitized value and reestablish a meaningful selection range of the input fields.

```js
function assureValidNumberValue({ currentTarget }, maxlength = 20) {
  const { value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = currentTarget;

  const sanitizedValue = value
    .replace(/[^\p{N}]/gu, '')
    .slice(0, maxlength);

  const deltaLength = value.length - sanitizedValue.length;

  currentTarget.value = sanitizedValue;
  currentTarget.setSelectionRange(selectionEnd - deltaLength, selectionEnd - deltaLength);
}

document
  .querySelector('input')
  .addEventListener('input', assureValidNumberValue);
```

```css
[type="text"] { display: block; width: 50%; }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="01234٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩56789" />
```